# excel (2010) - loop through each cell in a Range and draw an oval

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am new to vba and I am trying to make a macro to draw an oval round every circle in a Range
I've found a code to make an oval in a selected cell

```
Sub Add_Oval_in_ActiveCell()
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Range("A1:A6").Select
Range("A2").Activate
t = ActiveCell.Top
l = ActiveCell.Left
h = ActiveCell.Height
w = ActiveCell.Width
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, l, t, w, h).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Line
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    .Transparency = 0
    End With
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Line
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .Weight = 2.25
    End With
End Sub
```

This can draw an oval in cell A2

How I can make it to loop in a range of cells?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This traces oval for each cell in a range:

```
Sub sof20302984AddOvalInActiveCell()
  Dim t, l, h, w
  Dim aCell
  '
  'Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
  'Range("A1:A6").Select
  '
  For Each aCell In Range("A1:B6")
    aCell.Activate
    t = ActiveCell.Top
    l = ActiveCell.Left
    h = ActiveCell.Height
    w = ActiveCell.Width
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, l, t, w, h).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Line
      .Visible = msoTrue
      .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
      .Transparency = 0
      End With
      With Selection.ShapeRange.Line
      .Visible = msoTrue
      .Weight = 2.25
    End With
  Next
  Set aCell = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'try this one 
Set myDocument = Worksheets(1)
With myDocument.Shapes
    For Z = .Count To 1 Step -1
        With .Item(Z)
            If .Name = "oval" Then .Delete

        End With
    Next
End With



Dim t, l, h, w
  Dim aCell



  '
  For Each aCell In Range("A1:B6")
    aCell.Activate
    t = ActiveCell.Top
    l = ActiveCell.Left
    h = ActiveCell.Height
    w = ActiveCell.Width
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, l, t, w, h).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.Name = "oval"
    Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoFalse

    With Selection.ShapeRange.Line
      .Visible = msoTrue
      .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
      .Transparency = 0
      End With
      With Selection.ShapeRange.Line
      .Visible = msoTrue
      .Weight = 2.25
    End With
  Next
 Cells(1, 1).Activate
  Set aCell = Nothing
```

Comment: how is this an improvement over the already-approved answer? A bit of an explanation, rather than simply "Try this one!" might be helpful. That said, this question is almost a year old and was asked by a user who has not been back to Stack Overflow since December, 2013.  It's unlikely that he will ever return to review your answer...